# Is there a regex to capture a directory, without the whole line?

Tags: python, regex, powershell, pip

I would like to try automating the compiling of a python app I made using PowerShell.
In order to achieve, I have to get the directory name of where my python packages are installed as a variable.
I'll use the exemple of matplotlib.

```
pip show matplotlib
```

This allows me to get the following:

```
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.5.2
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\bschmidt\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
Requires: cycler, fonttools, kiwisolver, numpy, packaging, pillow, pyparsing, python-dateutil
```

Using *select-string*, I can manage to corner the desired line, containing the directory name.

```
Select-String -pattern "\bc:\\*\b"
```

It gives me the following line:

```
Location: c:\users\bschmidt\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.pyt ##hon.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
```

Now comes my problem: how can I isolate `c:\users\bschmidt\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages` ?

Comment: `'(?<=Location:\s*)\b[\w:\\.-]+\b'` might work for you (assuming the path will never have spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might for example use a capture group matching 1 or more non whitespace chars:

```
^Location:\s*(\S+)'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WCvOO0/1)

Example code

```
$Str = @"
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.5.2
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\bschmidt\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
Requires: cycler, fonttools, kiwisolver, numpy, packaging, pillow, pyparsing, python-dateutil
"@

$Pattern = '(?m)^Location:\s*(\S+)'
$Str -match $Pattern | Out-Null
$Matches[1] # First capturing group
```

Output

```
c:\users\bschmidt\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
```

---

Or more specific, matching `c:\` followed by the rest of the line:

```
^Location:\s*(c:\\.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YoQuSf/1)